# UITableViewCell width is not adjusting dynamically based on ios device type

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout, uitableview

My tableview cells are created entirely programmatically (I'm trying to learn to build an app from scratch without using storyboards) and the width of the cells is getting messed up.

Here is a screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4f3j.jpg of what the cell looks like in an iPhone 6 Plus. I'm trying to set the cell so that the UIView in the cell(self.view) gets adjusted automatically so that it fills the entire screen. I'm not sure why the width is staying static. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(instancetype)initWithTweet:(PCRTweet *)tweet reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    _tweet = tweet;

    reuse = reuseIdentifier;

    CGSize cellSize = self.contentView.frame.size;

    CGRect backgroundView = CGRectMake(10.f, 5.f, (cellSize.width-20.f), (cellSize.height + 90.f));


    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:backgroundView];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.view.layer.borderColor = background_color_gray.CGColor;
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.view];

    CGRect picView = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 65.f, 65.f);

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = background_color_gray;

}

return self;
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you using constraints on your tableview?

Comment: use self.view.frame.size.width-20.f
CGRect backgroundView = CGRectMake(10.f, 5.f, (self.view.frame.size.width -20.f), (cellSize.height + 90.f));

Comment: I suggest you to modify the frame in layourSubviews or use constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use auto-resizing for your view.

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read the points on following  checklist to ensure you doing it all right:

-[ ] Have you checked that your **contentView** is dynamically changing?

-[ ] Have you tried putting constraints programatically?

-[ ] Try using constraints on the largest view : will auto adjust the relative views

Apart from it, you can auto-resizing for your frame.

Comment: how do i check if contentview is dynamically changing?

Comment: since you are not using storyboard+constraints, you can try simply printing frame coordinates and dimensions.. a bit hacky way but worth a try.

Comment: when i logged the dimensions, the width comes up as 320 regardless of the device type

Comment: that means its not dynamically changing. Before that how does your container view shown on screen ? can you show? You can refer to this ( http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions )for screen size if you container view is SUPPOSED to be as same as screen of iphone

Comment: im not sure what the container view your referring to. this is what it looks like when it loads on a 6 plus. the white view is supposed to stretch to the outer bound. http://imgur.com/ki6txqg

Comment: the container view consists of chat elements as it's subview. so here i guess from the image, your container view is with white background. please try to put constraints on the right side between right screen bound and the white container view so that it dynamically stretches out with respect to width. another type of constraint you can apply is of aspect ratio with your container view and the width of device. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Art/view_formula_2x.png) refer here for more info about constraints

Answer (score 1):

You try this two UITableView Delegate method in table view class

**For Dynamic Height**

```
#pragma mark - UITableView Delegates

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView )tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath )indexPath {

     return 44.0;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView )tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath )indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**For Width (Get view controller width and take to backgroundView)**

```
CGSize viewWidth = self.contentView.superview.superview.superview.superview.frame.size;

// self.contentView.superview  -> return UITableViewCell
// self.contentView.superview.superview  -> return UITableViewWrapperView
// self.contentView.superview.superview.superview  -> return UITableView
// self.contentView.superview.superview.superview.superview  -> return View Controller

CGRect backgroundView = CGRectMake(10.f, 5.f, (viewWidth.width-20.f), (cellSize.height + 90.f));
```

Comment: that didn't help. the issue has to do with width not height

Comment: I tried adding         CGSize cellSize = self.contentView.superview.frame.size;
 but it didnt change anything